# My generic function for Retrofit interface creation get compiler error: inferred type is Class<T>? but Class<T!> was expected

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit in my Android (kotlin) project.

I created my interface:

```
interface StudentsInterface {
    @GET("foo/bar/{id}")
    suspend fun getStudent(@Path("id") myId: Int)
}
```

I created a `MyClient` class in which I defined a generic function for creating endpoint service out from any interface like above code defined:

```
class MyClient() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var  retrofit: Retrofit

    // this is my generic function
    fun <T> createService(interfaceClazz: Class<T>?): T {
        // Compiler error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Class<T>? but Class<T!> was expected
        return retrofit.create(interfaceClazz)
    }
}
```

So that in another class I can :

```
val sService = myClient.createService(StudentsInterface::class.java)
...
```

But when I build the project, I always get compiler error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Class<T>? but Class<T!> was expected` in the line of code `return retrofit.create(interfaceClazz)`

Why do I get this error? How to get rid of it?

Comment: You are trying to use a nullable type in a method that takes non-nullable arguments. Why do you need `interfaceClazz` to be nullable anyway? What are you expecting to be returned when it's `null`?

Comment: You should re-think your architecture. I assume that you're using Dagger2 (`@Inject` annotation), so you must declare explicit what service you're going to provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrofit create needs non nullable arguments. Try to make `interfaceClazz` non nullable

```
fun <T> createService(interfaceClazz: Class<T>): T {
    // No error now
    return retrofit.create(interfaceClazz)
}
```